# Java - Efficient way to transfer files to S3 from local directory

Tags: java, performance, amazon-s3, upload

I am working on a Spring Boot project to write and upload large number of files (couple million small size files) to S3. And my implementation right is like this using aws s3 sdk for java.

```
if("s3".equalsIgnoreCase(fileSystemType)) {
        PutObjectRequest request = PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket(s3BucketName).key(s3ObjectKey).build();
        s3Client.putObject(request, Paths.get(file));
}
```

For every file a Put request is executed which currently is not so efficient and takes a lot of time. Is there any way efficiently handle this scenario. Any references and suggestion would help.

Comment: You're trying to put objects (files) into S3, so a put operation is the way to do it. No getting around that without changing the structure... potentially, you can put the files into one object in S3 as some concatenation of all of the individual files. As a way to increase performance with the single file methods, you can look into using a concurrent approach (e.g. threads) to upload files concurrently, and wait for all of those concurrent processes to complete.

Comment: Another thing to look at could be the [v2 client](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2) which provide [CompletableFuture apis](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/S3AsyncOps.java#L68). Not sure if you'll get any gains in throughput, give it a go and measure! Alternatively use the v1 client and farm out puts to an ExecutorService.